# AttributeError: module 'circle' has no attribute 'pi'

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python. I was trying a simple problem in creating functions and saving in different module "circle" and invoking it in different one.

circle.py

```
def area(x):
    return pi*(x**2)

def circumference(x):
    return 2*pi*x

pi = 3.14159
```

test.py

```
import circle

print(circle.pi)
print(circle.area(3))
```

It gives an error-

```
AttributeError: module 'circle' has no attribute 'pi'
```

Comment: Please include actual code in your question, not screenshots.

Comment: Judging by the asterisk next to the file name in the tab (`circle.py*`), you have not saved the most recent version of the file. Perhaps the line that defines `pi` is not there yet.

Comment: Even after saving, shows the same

Comment: Remove the folder `__pycache__` and try again. Also, check `circle.__file__` after importing the module.

Comment: Did you place these two files under the same directory?